# Cannot access JAR file

Tags: java, file, batch-file, jar

I exported my Java code to a JAR file using Eclipse, and then tried to run the JAR file with the following batch file:

```
java -jar Readability.jar
pause
```

My JAR file is in the same directory. I tried running as an administrator and change directory command.

Comment: What happens when you run this batch file? Do you see an error message?

Comment: "Unable to access jarfile Readibility.jar"

Comment: Readibility.jar != Readability.jar

Comment: Thanks, that helped, but now I'm getting an Invalid or corrupt jar file error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the name for the JAR file within your batch matches the actual name of the JAR file that you are trying to run. That's usually what that error means. Like 
`Readibility.jar`, but your JAR's actual name is `Readability.jar`.

Comment: this answer looks familiar to me :D

Comment: haha yea, i hadnt refreshed my broswer, so i didnt see your comment until after i posted